# Long press in Google Maps

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-maps

Help me solve the problem. I'm trying to track a long click on the map in Google Maps but I can not do it. Here is an example of my code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var mMap: GMSMapView!

var longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()

@IBAction func longPress(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    testTextview.text = "You tapped at YES"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, 
 action: #selector(self.longPress))
 longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
 mMap.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)

 mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true 
 mMap.settings.compassButton = true 
 mMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 54.9044200, 
 longitude: 52.3154000, zoom: 15.0)
 }
}
```

Using this code does not happen. I tried all the methods that were on stackoverflow but also nothing happened.

Comment: Hi there- what happens if you remove the @IBAction decorator from the function? (You may need to replace it with @objc).

Comment: this method also does not work

Comment: @ildar1989 any feedback of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GMSMapView` class have a lot of different gestures recognisers, so you need add a `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` implementation adding this method to your viewController `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith`

***here is what you need to modify***

**add**

```
extension ViewController : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
{
    public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
    {
        return true
    }
}
```

**add**

```
longPressRecognizer.delegate = self
```

**below this line** `longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5`

**Full Code**

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var mMap: GMSMapView!

var longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()

@IBAction func longPress(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    testTextview.text = "You tapped at YES"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, 
 action: #selector(self.longPress))
 longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
 longPressRecognizer.delegate = self
 mMap.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)

 mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true 
 mMap.settings.compassButton = true 
 mMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 54.9044200, 
 longitude: 52.3154000, zoom: 15.0)
 }
}

extension ViewController : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
    {
        public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
        {
            return true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Just assign your viewController class as a delegate of GMSMapViewDelegate.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.mMap.delegate = self
    //....
}
```

and track long press in the following method...

```
extension ViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didLongPressAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        print(coordinate)
    }
}
```