# How can I make long-press event in MapKit

Tags: swift, annotations, mapkit

I can make click event of annotation in MapKit but How can I make long press event of annotation in MapKit?

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        let annotation = view.annotation
        let user = (annotation as! PointAnnotation).user
        let me = mainStore.state.profile
        if user === me {
            return
        }
        let vc = ChatVC.storyBoardInstance
        vc.user = user
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

This is code about click event.

Comment: Please check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135531/long-press-in-google-maps/49527046#49527046

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I think it's solution for Google Map I am using MapKit

Comment: Oops, my bad, sorry.

Comment: np, Do you think is it possible in MapKit?

Comment: I haven't use the MapKit, though, a quick search on Google led me here, https://medium.com/@calmone/ios-mapkit-in-swift-4-drop-the-pin-at-the-point-of-long-press-2bed878fdf93

Answer (score 4):

**Swift5** : in your viewDidLoad(),

```
    let lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, 
                         action:#selector(self.handleLongPress))
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1
    lpgr.delaysTouchesBegan = true
    lpgr.delegate = self
    self._mapView.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)
```

and implement this in your viewcontroller,

```
@objc func handleLongPress(gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended {
            return
        }
        else if gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {

            let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.mapView)

        let touchMapCoordinate =  self._mapView.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: _mapView)
        yourAnnotation.subtitle = "You long pressed here"
        yourAnnotation.coordinate = touchMapCoordinate
        self._mapView.addAnnotation(yourAnnotation)
    }
```

}

Comment: I am getting issue in lpgr.delegate = self

Comment: could you post the error here? did you add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to your viewcontroller?

Comment: Hi @Cosmo I could see I can receive touchPoint with coordinates now. so should I compare that touchpoint with my annotations?

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could add a Long Press Gesture Recognizer to the MapView, then check the state of the recognizer in the selection method for the annotation. If you want something to happen while the gesture is in progress, for example, you could check that the state of the recognizer isn't .ended or .cancelled.

For example:

```
if recognizer.state == .ended || recognizer.state == .cancelled || recognizer.state == .failed {
            // this would cover the gesture no longer being in progress
        } else if recognizer.state == .began {
            // handle the gesture beginning
        }
```

I always add the gesture recognizer in the storyboard, by simply dropping it onto the map then creating outlets/actions. If you want to do it programmatically you can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer).

Comment: Well, could you upload some code example? Thank you